# Sending Microsoft Teams message when Jenkins node is offline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, microsoft-teams, jenkins-groovy

## Question

I need to verify the status of a worker node in Jenkins.  I need to verify that the node is online.  Additionally I need send a Microsoft Teams message or an API call when the node is offline.  How can I accomplish this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Teams Configuration

> First you will need to install the [Office 365 Connector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Office-365-Connector/) plugin on Jenkins.

Go into your Teams channel and select *Connector* from the options menu

[image: Teams Connectors]

Once you are in the Connector screen search for and click Configure on the Jenkins Connector

[image: Configure Jenkins in Teams]

You will be prompted to supply a name for the connector.  Supply a name of your choice and click create.  In Step 2 you will see a Webhook URL.  Copy that URL then scroll to the bottom and click done

[image: Teams Webhook URL]

## Jenkins Configuration

Now that you have the Teams Webhook URL you can write your Jenkins Pipeline script.  Remember, you need to have the [Office 365 Connector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Office-365-Connector/) plugin installed.  Create a new Pipeline and use the following Groovy code

```
node {
    
    def nodeName = "EC2 (Integrations) - JDK11 Worker (i-0622e9de9e7aaa70d)"
    def isOnline =  Jenkins.instance.nodes.find { it.name == nodeName }?.computer?.online
    def webhook = "https://domain.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/e68084ea-a0a7-49dfJenkinsCI/1c8caa98-bbb8-43b8-abbe-eda2b45832bd"

    if( !isOnline ) {
        office365ConnectorSend message: "${nodeName} is Offline!", status: "FAILURE", webhookUrl: "${webhook}", color: "d00000"
    }

}
```

> You will need to change the *nodeName* and *webhook* variable to be the name of your node and the webhook URL you copied from teams, respectively. Thanks to [@NoamHelmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13110835/noam-helmer) for suggesting the use of the Jenkins API over the REST API

You may receive the following error

> Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance

To resolve this error either run the pipeline **outside the Groovy Sandbox** or approve that script signature.

## Additional Information

You can also retrieve the offline status of your node through the following REST API

```
https://${JENKINS_URL}/computer/${NODE}/api/json
```

The response body from a GET request to this endpoint is as follows ( I have slimed the response down )

```
{
    "displayName": "JDK11-EC2-Instance",
    "numExecutors": 2,
    "offline": false,
    "offlineCause": null,
    "offlineCauseReason": "",
    "oneOffExecutors": [],
    "temporarilyOffline": false,
    "absoluteRemotePath": "/home/ec2-user"
}
```

If you wanted to retrieve the data from the rest service you could do so by using the following Groovy script

```
node {

    def nodeName = "EC2 (Integrations) - JDK11 Worker (i-0622e9de9e7aaa70d)"
    def webhook = "https://domain.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/e68084ea-a0a7-49dfJenkinsCI/1c8caa98-bbb8-43b8-abbe-eda2b45832bd"
    def response = httpRequest authentication: 'jenkins-credential-id', url: "https://${env.JENKINS_URL}/computer/${nodeName}/api/json"
    
    def json = readJSON text: response.content
    
    if( json['offline'] ) {
        office365ConnectorSend message: "${nodeName} is Offline!", status: "FAILURE", webhookUrl: "${webhook}", color: "d00000"
    }
}
```

> This example uses the [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/) plugin, the [HTTP Request](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/)  plugin, and the [Office 365 Connector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Office-365-Connector/) plugin

## Multiple Agents

Here is an example showing the code modifications for multiple agents.

```
node {
    
    def nodeNames = ["EC2 (Integrations) - JDK11 Worker (i-0622e9de9e7aaa70d)", "EC2 (Integrations) - JDK7 Worker (i-1223i1de9e7eea70d)"]
    def webhook = "https://domain.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/e68084ea-a0a7-49dfJenkinsCI/1c8caa98-bbb8-43b8-abbe-eda2b45832bd"

    nodeNames.each{ nodeName ->
        def isOnline =  Jenkins.instance.nodes.find { it.name == nodeName }?.computer?.online

        if( !isOnline ) {
            office365ConnectorSend message: "${nodeName} is Offline!", status: "FAILURE", webhookUrl: "${webhook}", color: "d00000"
        }
    }

}
```